# I am stuck updating a dependency which is already up to date

Tags: angular, dependencies, updates, ng

I am trying to update Angular from 12 to 16.

I want to use the three.js library and it needs Angular/cli 16 at least to work.

So angular/cli is already up to 16 but angular has been updated to 13 so far. I managed that much using

```
npm run ng update
```

and then went into `package.json` and increased the package numbers and typed

```
npm i.
```

That worked to get from 12 to 13, and so I try it again.

It tells me one of my packages needs to update even though I know it is already up to 13.4.0 already.

So regardless I type `npm run ng update @angular/core@13`

However it insists I am already updated.

So then I get desperate and I delete my node_modules and recreate using npm install. However nothing seems to work.

Any ideas, I am desperate.

[image]

Comment: Im not sure about your issue, but maybe this link can help:
https://update.angular.io/

Comment: Thankyou, but I actually started with this page heh heh. Obviously before posting this I searched for an answer first.

Comment: I have now managed to update angular/core to 13.4.0 but there is a still a problem. When I run npm run ng update, it still insists that the core is 12.0.5 and yet it is definately updated. Which means I cannot update Angular.

Answer (score 1):

Well I finally managed to update it after 4 days of trying.
I cannot give you a good answer as I have tried lots of different commands to get it to work. I still have an error where it can't find an SCSS sheet, but so far only one. I hope I can sort this soon.

I can only say vaguely what I did. I deleted node-modules and recreated them a few times. Finally I managed to update Angular/cli, but it had some peer dependancy errors. So in package.json I upgrade each one and then did an npm install. Now when I do npm start I only get one error, which I am trying to work out.

PS. Ok I have finally got rid of all the errors. It is a painstaking process, but the page is finally ready for me to add more content. I wish they would make it easier to upgrade angular.